# Active record query with associations

Tags: mysql, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Two models: Genre and Movie. Genre has many Movies, Movie belongs to Genre.

```
  create_table "genres", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "genre_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I want to return(in JSON) list of all the movies(title), with genre(name, and number of the movies in this genre), but I want to use Movie model to create a query(Movie.some_query, not Genre.some_query). I done something like:

> Movie.select(:id, :title).joins(:genre).select('name as genre_name')

which gives me format like: 
[{"id":1,"title":"Titanic","genre_name":"Horror"}

I would like to add the number of movies in genre as last record. When I try to use .count or .length methods, console returns error.

Controller:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class MoviesController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json

            def index
                respond_with Movie.select(:id, :title).joins(:genre).select('name as genre_name')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the full code you're using to dump records to JSON?

Comment: Edit your question and put it there instead :)

Comment: Done. Code look ugly in the comment section :)

Comment: At this point I can say that the better way there was to use QueryObject pattern. When the application grows, it becomes unreadable.